# catkinizing xacro package for Groovy

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I've noticed that the [xacro](https://kforge.ros.org/common/xacro/file/cf7e84d93538) package is still dry because there were apparently issues catkinizing it. Could someone shed some light on what these issues exactly were? It would be really useful having it catkinized.

D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58579/catkinizing-xacro-package-for-groovy/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These two tickets have quite a bit of discussion and sum it up well:

- https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/1
- https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/2

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1